# How to send Push Notifications in java Play Framework

Tags: push-notification, server, playframework-2.6

I am new to JAVA Play framework and i want to send push notifications to android and IOS clients.For that i choose to integrate FCM. Is there any library or other module to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FCM has no Java SDK, so no, you need to use https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref
Play provides the WSClient to make HTTP requests : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWS